# Convert png or jpg image to Base64 string in Android

Tags: android

In my Application, I need to convert Image to Base64 format.
Could anyone please let me know how can I do that?

Please forward your valuable suggestions.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android has a class for doing this.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html

Comment: This class doesnot exist in Android 1.5.

Answer (score 0):

This question has already been asked before..

You can try using this class to encode or decode base64 String

http://www.source-code.biz/base64coder/java/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Base64 Android class:

```
String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

You'll have to convert your image into a byte array though. Here's an example:

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/path/to/image.jpg");
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos); //bm is the bitmap object   
byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
```