# ways and usefull libraries for sending image from client (android) to server (Spring)

Tags: android, spring, rest

I  find the next  possible  ways

1)  convert Image into Base64 string and put this string into the JSON object.
    [Send image as json entry android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15565928/send-image-as-json-entry-android)

2)  create an array of bytes out of the bitmap, and then create a new string with that array of bytes, and then send it to the server

http://blog.3dmick.com/2012/06/android-app-for-uploading-images-on-server/

Which else libraries or ways do u know ?? 
Which ways are popular on the enteptise projects?

Comment: Why not simply send the image as byte array in the body of a POST request? The is the smallest regarding the size of the uploaded data...

Comment: im a new  in programming. but how about a huge image (15 mb)? I convert this image as byte array. then my phone suddenly switched off  and uploading was interrupted on 98%. at the next time i want to finish my uploading. Are the libraries which also include such cases ?