# How to store an image using sharedpreferences? Android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-sharedpreferences

My code below put an image from gallery to my ImageButton
But always when i leave the application or move to another activity the image don't save and the first background appear again.

I need help, how can i save the image that i define to be my ImageButton background

I read about sharedpreferences, but i don't know how to use on my app

-

-
My CLASS

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    //Adding the picture bit   

    imgButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.AddPic);
    imgButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent GaleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(GaleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
        }
    });
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        Uri SelectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] FilePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        Cursor SelectedCursor = getContentResolver().query(SelectedImage, FilePathColumn, null, null, null);
        SelectedCursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = SelectedCursor.getColumnIndex(FilePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = SelectedCursor.getString(columnIndex);
        SelectedCursor.close();

      //  Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath)); 
       // btnOpenGalery .setImageBitmap(d);
        imgButton.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), picturePath, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

}
```

my XML

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/AddPic"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:onClick="AddPic"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Remove the android:background="@drawable/ic_lancher" line from your ImageButton, it may help you if in case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save Image in shared preference in Android | Shared preference issue in Android with Image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18072448/how-to-save-image-in-shared-preference-in-android-shared-preference-issue-in-a)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use sharedPreferences, use the below code:

```
  SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("data",  context.MODE_PRIVATE);

  //Adding the picture bit    

imgButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.AddPic);
imgButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
    @Override 
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent GaleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(GaleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
    } 
}); 

if(sharedPreferences!=null)
String path = sharedPreferences.getString("path", null);
if(path!=null)
  imgButton.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path));




} 
@Override 
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
    Uri SelectedImage = data.getData();
    String[] FilePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

    Cursor SelectedCursor = getContentResolver().query(SelectedImage, FilePathColumn, null, null, null);
    SelectedCursor.moveToFirst();

    int columnIndex = SelectedCursor.getColumnIndex(FilePathColumn[0]);
    String picturePath = SelectedCursor.getString(columnIndex);
    SelectedCursor.close();
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("path", picturePath);
    editor.commit();

  //  Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));  
   // btnOpenGalery .setImageBitmap(d); 
    imgButton.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), picturePath, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

}

Comment: get error on context:  context cannot be resolved to a variable. What i do?

Comment: remove it! not required here.

Comment: didnt work :/

a part of logcat:
 10-15 06:40:44.795: E/AndroidRuntime(505): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-15 06:40:44.795: E/AndroidRuntime(505):  at com.example.camera2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:38)

Comment: i eliminated the line: sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("data",  context.MODE_PRIVATE);
 , as you said, and didnt work again

Answer (score 0):

I did't do this task ealier but as I guess you can store image as Base64 string in Preferences . When you want to get that image again then convert Base64 string to corresponding image .
You can follow  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531408/convert-png-or-jpg-image-to-base64-string-in-android) link to convert a image in Base64 string , and to convert a Base64 String to a image see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17506428/convert-base64-string-to-image-in-java)